# Issue with Odata Time format in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Issue with Odata Time format

When i am using GetRows to fetch rows from one table and inserting same data into another table . i am getting error 'formatDateTime', the value provided for date time string 'PT17H' was not valid. The datetime string must match ISO 8601 format.'. 
When I am connecting with Azure SQL , it is working fine and returning Time in Format "19:30:00". Issue is with On-Prem SQL only

Comment: When i am connecting with Azure SQL , it is working fine and returning Time in Format "19:30:00",.

Comment: Issue is with On-Prem SQL only

Comment: As far as I know, "PT17H" doesn't match ISO8601 format, so it should fail in azure sql too. May I know the expression when you insert it in your logic app ? And may I know the type of the column in your table(both azure sql and prem sql).

Comment: data type is Time(7) . I am getting the data from HTTP API . it is getting data in format HH:MM:SS and able to save in same format . When another logic app is fetching rows , it is picking data in PT17H Odata Format and unable to save to another table with same data type . But  it is working fine for Azure SQL Database

Comment: You mean the logic app works fine for Azure sql but fail in prem sql ? Or just the the HTTP api works fine for Azure sql and logic app also fail in azure sql ?

Comment: Hi Mohit, may I know if your problem is solved ? If not solved, maybe you can compare the version of azure sql and prem sql. As far as I know, azure sql use the latest sql version as default.